# How to recover currency information from broken data set?

Tags: text-mining

This is so not my area, so I apologize if this is not in scope for this stack.

I am cleaning up (for personal entertainment and making visualization to share with others) survey data ([download, 9MB](http://s.wordpress.org/resources/survey/wp2011-survey.tar.gz)) that went through some manipulations to be anonymized before getting released to the public.

One of the questions was about hourly payment rate and allowed free form text answer. Some of those answers got badly broken characters, two most common cases shown in image below:

[image]

I would hate to discard those answers, but I am at loss how to revert them to meaningful state.

1. Ask for better data dump - poked related people about it, but not too hopeful.
2. Try to determine which characters ended up this way. Dealing with encodings is always troublesome and these don't look like any broken characters I ever seen before so I have no idea where to start and if there are tools available to help with this. That might not even be a valid characters or currency symbols at all.
3. Try to match broken characters to valid currency characters. I strongly suspect one of the two might be € character and other might be £ given that survey was slanted towards English-speaking countries. However will I be able to reliably back up such guess by relative quantity of character to other answers? Unfortunately geo data was not provided, so I can't match answers to countries.

Comment: Given that such corruption is pervasive, how can you even be confident that *any* of the data are correct?  For instance, perhaps most of a record was deleted, so that the value in one (original) line is now associated with the currency in the next (original) line.  This seems like a data forensics problem which is best solved by having the "manipulations" redone correctly.

Comment: @whuber there are answers where it seems sane in context, for example `ЊЈ20 - ЊЈ30 per hour depending on the client`. It would be great to just get my hands on better data dump, but until (and if ever) that happens I want to try and salvage what I can from what I have.

Comment: I don't think it's in Unicode; if you have Textpad on Windows, Textpad is very good at identifying which encoding it's in.  When I boot up Windows later on, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @jbowman Notepad++ (my usual plain text editor) and Textpad (just downloaded) both identify encoding as Macintosh ANSI

Comment: @Rarst - same here.  I tried to convert to UTF-8 and Unicode, but the bad characters appear unaffected.  It may be that the original data was in different encodings, depending upon source, and it all got merged w/o conversion, in which case you may have to go back to your source.

Comment: With just one exception, the only unintelligible text I can find in that document is "ä‰å" (0xE4A2E5).  It does not correspond to any recognizable Unicode corruption. Notably, the only major Western currency symbol I *cannot* find in this field is the Euro, "€".  Coincidence?  There are some auxiliary indications that these records are associated with European countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was confirmed that this was caused by export bug in survey software and characters do correspond to euro and pound.

> As you suspected.
>
> [image]
>
> it's a [@Polldaddy](https://twitter.com/#!/Polldaddy) export to csv bug
>
> *[Pete Davies](https://twitter.com/#!/pjadavies/status/155479113770082306)*

Comment: Hmm...There's something strange about this display of the data.  Using either Wordpad or Excel, the "Euro" appears as "ä‰å" (in most fonts, anyway) and the pound appears correctly.

Comment: @whuber that might have to do with my Windows set to Russian locale. In your case symbols in broken euro look latin, in my case (as in image) they look cyrillic.